# how can I sort my data by the rate of another table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.7 developing a project. I have two tables,one is users table, another is orders table.The User model has a hasMany orders relation(the foreign key in the orders table is user_id).In the orders table,there is a column named "win", which value is 1 or 0.When I select the users , I want to sort the users by their orders win rate(the users total count of win orders(win=1) / the user's total count orders).How can I make this possible.

Comment: Are you asking for a query?

Comment: can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: User::has('win', '=', 1)->get(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User::withCount(['orders as WinRate' => function($q){
    $q->where('win', 1)->get();
    $total = ($q / count($q->whereIn('win', [1,0])->get()));
    return $total;
}])
->with('orders')
->orderBy('WinRate', 'ASC')->get();
```

Can you try this.